# Inserción de ficha de stock en un SP para emitir ordenes de compra en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure, sql-server-2012

Soy nuevo en StackOverflow y es mi primera vez preguntando en esta comunidad, por lo tanto, si ustedes notan que tengo algún error al redactar estas preguntas, o tienen sugerencias para que mis preguntas sean más entendibles, bienvenidos sean.

Resulta que estoy desarrollando una aplicación que se encarga de gestionar los productos, existencias y facturación de un negocio.
El problema es que estoy estancado con el desarrollo de un procedimiento almacenado en SQL Server 2012 que se me está complicando.
El tema es este:
Entre las tablas que tengo de la base de datos, estoy operando con las siguientes tablas:

```sql
---Tabla de proveedores
CREATE TABLE PROVEEDOR
(
PROV_ID_PROVEEDOR int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
PROV_RAZON_SOCIAL varchar(MAX) NOT NULL,
PROV_FECHA_ALTA date DEFAULT GETDATE() NOT NULL,
PROV_ID_CONDICION_IVA smallint NOT NULL,
PROV_CUIT bigint NOT NULL,  
PROV_DOMICILIO_CALLE varchar(MAX) NOT NULL,
PROV_DOMICILIO_NUMERO int NOT NULL,
PROV_DOMICILIO_PISO int,
PROV_DOMICILIO_DEPARTAMENTO varchar(16),
PROV_ID_LOCALIDAD int NOT NULL,
PROV_EMAIL varchar(MAX),
PROV_ACTIVO bit NOT NULL,
PROV_ID_TELEFONO int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES TELEFONO(TELE_ID_TELEFONO) NOT NULL
)

---Tabla de productos registrados en el negocio
CREATE TABLE PRODUCTO
(
PROD_ID_PRODUCTO int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
PROD_NOMBRE varchar(MAX) NOT NULL,
PROD_ID_MARCA int NOT NULL,
PROD_ID_CATEGORIA int NOT NULL,
PROD_DESCRIPCION varchar(MAX) NOT NULL,
PROD_STOCK_MINIMO int NOT NULL,
PROD_PORCENTAJE_GANANCIA int NOT NULL,
PROD_ACTIVO bit NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (PROD_ID_MARCA) REFERENCES MARCA(MARC_ID_MARCA),
FOREIGN KEY (PROD_ID_CATEGORIA) REFERENCES CATEGORIA_PRODUCTO(CATE_ID_CATEGORIA)
)

---Tabla que registra la orden de compra de productos a un proveedor
CREATE TABLE ORDEN_COMPRA
(
ORCOM_ID_ORDEN int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
ORCOM_ID_PROVEEDOR int NOT NULL,
ORCOM_FECHA_COMPRA date DEFAULT GETDATE() NOT NULL,
ORCOM_SUBTOTAL money NOT NULL,
ORCOM_PRECIO_IVA money NOT NULL,
ORCOM_TOTAL money NOT NULL,
ORCOM_COSTO_ENVIO money,
FOREIGN KEY (ORCOM_ID_PROVEEDOR) REFERENCES PROVEEDOR(PROV_ID_PROVEEDOR)
)

---Tabla que registra el detalle de los productos de la orden de compra
CREATE TABLE DETALLE_ORDEN_COMPRA
(
DETCOM_ID_DETALLE int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
DETCOM_ID_ORDEN int NOT NULL,
DETCOM_ID_PRODUCTO int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES PRODUCTO (PROD_ID_PRODUCTO) NOT NULL,
DETCOM_CANTIDAD int NOT NULL,
DETCOM_PRECIO_UNITARIO money NOT NULL,
DETCOM_PRECIO_TOTAL money NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE FICHA_STOCK
(
STOCK_ID_STOCK int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
STOCK_ID_PRODUCTO int NOT NULL,
STOCK_FECHA_OPERACION date DEFAULT GETDATE() NOT NULL,
STOCK_ENTRADA_CANTIDAD int,
STOCK_ENTRADA_PRECIO_UNITARIO money,
STOCK_ENTRADA_TOTAL money,
STOCK_SALIDA_CANTIDAD int,
STOCK_SALIDA_PRECIO_UNITARIO money,
STOCK_SALIDA_TOTAL money,
STOCK_EXISTENCIA_CANTIDAD int,
STOCK_EXISTENCIA_PRECIO_UNITARIO money,
STOCK_EXISTENCIA_TOTAL money,
FOREIGN KEY (STOCK_ID_PRODUCTO) REFERENCES PRODUCTO (PROD_ID_PRODUCTO)
)
```

Bien. De estas tablas tengo que ejecutar un procedimiento almacenado llamado `sp_EMITIR_ORDEN_COMPRA`que se encarga de realizar las inserciones en las tablas anteriormente mencionadas.
El tema es que tengo problemas con el código del SP, el cual lo estoy programando realmente mal. Este es el código del SP:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_EMITIR_ORDEN_COMPRA
(
@IDProveedor int,
@Subtotal money,
@PrecioIVA money,
@Total money,
@CostoEnvio money,
@DetalleProductos TYPE_DETALLE_ORDEN_COMPRA READONLY,
@IDOrdenEmitida int OUT
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @IDOrden int, @Error int
DECLARE @StockExistencia TABLE
(
STOCK_ID_STOCK int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
STOCK_ID_PRODUCTO int,
STOCK_ENTRADA_CANTIDAD int,
STOCK_ENTRADA_PRECIO_UNITARIO money,
STOCK_ENTRADA_TOTAL money,
STOCK_EXISTENCIA_CANTIDAD int,
STOCK_EXISTENCIA_PRECIO_UNITARIO money,
STOCK_EXISTENCIA_TOTAL money
)
DECLARE @ListaProductos TABLE
(
DETCOM_ID_DETALLE int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
DETCOM_ID_ORDEN int,
DETCOM_ID_PRODUCTO int,
DETCOM_CANTIDAD int,
DETCOM_PRECIO_UNITARIO money,
DETCOM_PRECIO_TOTAL money
)

BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRY
    INSERT INTO ORDEN_COMPRA
    (
    ORCOM_ID_PROVEEDOR,
    ORCOM_SUBTOTAL,
    ORCOM_PRECIO_IVA,
    ORCOM_TOTAL,
    ORCOM_COSTO_ENVIO
    )
    VALUES
    (
    @IDProveedor,
    @Subtotal,
    @PrecioIVA,
    @Total,
    @CostoEnvio
    )
    SET @IDOrden = IDENT_CURRENT('ORDEN_COMPRA')

    INSERT INTO @ListaProductos
    (
    DETCOM_ID_PRODUCTO,
    DETCOM_CANTIDAD,
    DETCOM_PRECIO_UNITARIO,
    DETCOM_PRECIO_TOTAL
    )
    SELECT
        DETCOM_ID_PRODUCTO, 
        DETCOM_CANTIDAD, 
        DETCOM_PRECIO_UNITARIO, 
        DETCOM_PRECIO_TOTAL 
    FROM @DetalleProductos

    UPDATE @ListaProductos
    SET DETCOM_ID_ORDEN = @IDOrden

    INSERT INTO DETALLE_ORDEN_COMPRA
    (
    DETCOM_ID_ORDEN,
    DETCOM_ID_PRODUCTO,
    DETCOM_CANTIDAD,
    DETCOM_PRECIO_UNITARIO,
    DETCOM_PRECIO_TOTAL
    )
    SELECT DETCOM_ID_ORDEN, 
        DETCOM_ID_PRODUCTO, 
        DETCOM_CANTIDAD, 
        DETCOM_PRECIO_UNITARIO, 
        DETCOM_PRECIO_TOTAL 
    FROM @ListaProductos

    INSERT INTO FICHA_STOCK
    (
    STOCK_ID_PRODUCTO,
    STOCK_ENTRADA_CANTIDAD,
    STOCK_ENTRADA_PRECIO_UNITARIO,
    STOCK_ENTRADA_TOTAL,
    STOCK_EXISTENCIA_CANTIDAD,
    STOCK_EXISTENCIA_PRECIO_UNITARIO,
    STOCK_EXISTENCIA_TOTAL
    )
    SELECT 
    l.DETCOM_ID_PRODUCTO,
            l.DETCOM_CANTIDAD,
            l.DETCOM_PRECIO_UNITARIO,
            l.DETCOM_PRECIO_TOTAL,
            l.DETCOM_CANTIDAD + ISNULL(s.STOCK_EXISTENCIA_CANTIDAD, 0),
            l.DETCOM_PRECIO_TOTAL + ISNULL(s.STOCK_EXISTENCIA_TOTAL, 0)
            / l.DETCOM_CANTIDAD + ISNULL(s.STOCK_EXISTENCIA_CANTIDAD, 0),
            l.DETCOM_PRECIO_TOTAL + ISNULL(s.STOCK_EXISTENCIA_TOTAL, 0)
    FROM @ListaProductos l LEFT JOIN FICHA_STOCK s
    ON l.DETCOM_ID_PRODUCTO = s.STOCK_ID_PRODUCTO
    GROUP BY l.DETCOM_ID_PRODUCTO, 
            l.DETCOM_CANTIDAD, 
            l.DETCOM_PRECIO_UNITARIO, 
            l.DETCOM_PRECIO_TOTAL, 
            s.STOCK_EXISTENCIA_CANTIDAD,
            s.STOCK_EXISTENCIA_PRECIO_UNITARIO,
            s.STOCK_EXISTENCIA_TOTAL
    SET @Error = @@ERROR
    SET @IDOrdenEmitida = @IDOrden
    COMMIT
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
ROLLBACK
RETURN @Error
END CATCH
```

El tema es que funcione de la siguiente manera. Primero inserta en la tabla `ORDEN_COMPRA`, después inserta en `DETALLE_ORDEN_COMPRA` con los campos del parámetro de tipo `TABLE`. Hasta ahí el SP funciona bien y hace las inserciones correctamente. EL problema es con la tabla `FICHA_STOCK`.
En primer lugar, mi tabla de la Ficha de Stock tiene 6 columnas en 3 "grupos" (entradas, salidas y existencias). Cuando realizo la órden de compra, el SP tiene que hacer las actualizaciones en la Ficha de Stock: primero debe insertar en las 3 tablas de entrada(`STOCK_ENTRADA_CANTIDAD, STOCK_ENTRADA_PRECIO_UNITARIO, STOCK_ENTRADA_TOTAL`) con los datos de la orden de compra para cada producto. Después tiene que insertar lo siguiente:

Sí ya hay existencias registradas de alguno de los productos que pedí al proveedor en la Ficha de Stock, tiene que hacer estos cálculos:

1. Cantidad de unidades de cada producto que entra + Cantidad de unidades de cada producto que había en existencia.
2. Precio total de cada producto que entra + Precio total de cada producto que había en existencia.
3. Luego realizar la división entre la suma de estos dos (Suma de precio total / Suma de la cantidad) para obtener el precio unitario final en existencia. Algo similar a lo que está escrito en el SP.

Si no hay registros de alguno de los productos que pedí, entonces el SP solo tiene que insertar las entradas y luego las existencias del producto que no tenía existencias previas. Antes de terminar la transacción, el SP asigna el ID de Orden (obtenido de la función `IDENT_CURRENT`) al parametro de salida `@IDOrdenEmitida`, el cual me sirve para luego poder realizar el reporte en Visual Studio que me permite llenar los campos de la orden de compra que acabo de emitir con ese mismo ID.

El problema es que se me complica el tema de la sentencia `IF EXISTS`, ya que no realiza las inserciones en la base.
Tengo 2 versiones del mismo SP, la que les acabo de mostrar es la que no tiene condición `IF`. La segunda versión es la que sí tiene condición `IF` y la que me está tirando errores (o mejor dicho, me hace `ROLLBACK` como consecuencia del error:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_EMITIR_ORDEN_COMPRA
(
@IDProveedor int,
@Subtotal money,
@PrecioIVA money,
@Total money,
@CostoEnvio money,
@DetalleProductos TYPE_DETALLE_ORDEN_COMPRA READONLY
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @IDOrden int, @Error int
DECLARE @StockExistencia TABLE
(
STOCK_ID_STOCK int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
STOCK_ID_PRODUCTO int,
STOCK_ENTRADA_CANTIDAD int,
STOCK_ENTRADA_PRECIO_UNITARIO money,
STOCK_ENTRADA_TOTAL money,
STOCK_EXISTENCIA_CANTIDAD int,
STOCK_EXISTENCIA_PRECIO_UNITARIO money,
STOCK_EXISTENCIA_TOTAL money
)
DECLARE @ListaProductos TABLE
(
DETCOM_ID_DETALLE int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
DETCOM_ID_ORDEN int,
DETCOM_ID_PRODUCTO int,
DETCOM_CANTIDAD int,
DETCOM_PRECIO_UNITARIO money,
DETCOM_PRECIO_TOTAL money
)

BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRY
    INSERT INTO ORDEN_COMPRA
    (
    ORCOM_ID_PROVEEDOR,
    ORCOM_SUBTOTAL,
    ORCOM_PRECIO_IVA,
    ORCOM_TOTAL,
    ORCOM_COSTO_ENVIO
    )
    VALUES
    (
    @IDProveedor,
    @Subtotal,
    @PrecioIVA,
    @Total,
    @CostoEnvio
    )
    SET @IDOrden = IDENT_CURRENT('ORDEN_COMPRA')

    INSERT INTO @ListaProductos
    (
    DETCOM_ID_PRODUCTO,
    DETCOM_CANTIDAD,
    DETCOM_PRECIO_UNITARIO,
    DETCOM_PRECIO_TOTAL
    )
    SELECT
        DETCOM_ID_PRODUCTO, 
        DETCOM_CANTIDAD, 
        DETCOM_PRECIO_UNITARIO, 
        DETCOM_PRECIO_TOTAL 
    FROM @DetalleProductos

    UPDATE @ListaProductos
    SET DETCOM_ID_ORDEN = @IDOrden

    INSERT INTO DETALLE_ORDEN_COMPRA
    (
    DETCOM_ID_ORDEN,
    DETCOM_ID_PRODUCTO,
    DETCOM_CANTIDAD,
    DETCOM_PRECIO_UNITARIO,
    DETCOM_PRECIO_TOTAL
    )
    SELECT DETCOM_ID_ORDEN, 
        DETCOM_ID_PRODUCTO, 
        DETCOM_CANTIDAD, 
        DETCOM_PRECIO_UNITARIO, 
        DETCOM_PRECIO_TOTAL 
    FROM @ListaProductos
        
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM FICHA_STOCK WHERE STOCK_ID_PRODUCTO = (SELECT DETCOM_ID_PRODUCTO FROM @ListaProductos))
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO FICHA_STOCK
    (
    STOCK_ID_PRODUCTO,
    STOCK_ENTRADA_CANTIDAD,
    STOCK_ENTRADA_PRECIO_UNITARIO,
    STOCK_ENTRADA_TOTAL,
    STOCK_EXISTENCIA_CANTIDAD,
    STOCK_EXISTENCIA_PRECIO_UNITARIO,
    STOCK_EXISTENCIA_TOTAL
    )
    SELECT l.DETCOM_ID_PRODUCTO,
            l.DETCOM_CANTIDAD,
            l.DETCOM_PRECIO_UNITARIO,
            l.DETCOM_PRECIO_TOTAL,
            l.DETCOM_CANTIDAD + ISNULL(s.STOCK_EXISTENCIA_CANTIDAD, 0),
            (l.DETCOM_PRECIO_TOTAL + ISNULL(s.STOCK_EXISTENCIA_TOTAL, 0)) / (l.DETCOM_CANTIDAD + ISNULL(s.STOCK_EXISTENCIA_CANTIDAD, 0)),
            l.DETCOM_PRECIO_TOTAL + ISNULL(s.STOCK_EXISTENCIA_TOTAL, 0)
    FROM @ListaProductos l LEFT JOIN FICHA_STOCK s
    ON l.DETCOM_ID_PRODUCTO = s.STOCK_ID_PRODUCTO
    GROUP BY l.DETCOM_ID_PRODUCTO, 
            l.DETCOM_CANTIDAD, 
            l.DETCOM_PRECIO_UNITARIO, 
            l.DETCOM_PRECIO_TOTAL, 
            s.STOCK_EXISTENCIA_CANTIDAD,
            s.STOCK_EXISTENCIA_PRECIO_UNITARIO,
            s.STOCK_EXISTENCIA_TOTAL
    END

    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM FICHA_STOCK WHERE STOCK_ID_PRODUCTO = (SELECT DETCOM_ID_PRODUCTO FROM @ListaProductos))
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO FICHA_STOCK
        (
        STOCK_ID_PRODUCTO,
        STOCK_ENTRADA_CANTIDAD,
        STOCK_ENTRADA_PRECIO_UNITARIO,
        STOCK_ENTRADA_TOTAL,
        STOCK_EXISTENCIA_CANTIDAD,
        STOCK_EXISTENCIA_PRECIO_UNITARIO,
        STOCK_EXISTENCIA_TOTAL
        )
        SELECT DETCOM_ID_PRODUCTO, DETCOM_CANTIDAD, DETCOM_PRECIO_UNITARIO, DETCOM_PRECIO_TOTAL, DETCOM_CANTIDAD, DETCOM_PRECIO_UNITARIO, DETCOM_PRECIO_TOTAL FROM @ListaProductos
        GROUP BY DETCOM_ID_PRODUCTO, DETCOM_CANTIDAD, DETCOM_PRECIO_UNITARIO, DETCOM_PRECIO_TOTAL
    END
    SET @Error = @@ERROR
    COMMIT
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
ROLLBACK
RETURN @Error
END CATCH
```

Y si yo hago consulta en la ficha de stock:

```sql
SELECT p.PROD_NOMBRE, s.STOCK_FECHA_OPERACION, 
    s.STOCK_ENTRADA_CANTIDAD, 
    s.STOCK_ENTRADA_PRECIO_UNITARIO, 
    s.STOCK_ENTRADA_TOTAL, 
    s.STOCK_SALIDA_CANTIDAD, 
    s.STOCK_SALIDA_PRECIO_UNITARIO, 
    s.STOCK_SALIDA_TOTAL, 
    s.STOCK_EXISTENCIA_CANTIDAD, 
    s.STOCK_EXISTENCIA_PRECIO_UNITARIO, 
    s.STOCK_EXISTENCIA_TOTAL 
FROM PRODUCTO p 
INNER JOIN FICHA_STOCK s 
ON p.PROD_ID_PRODUCTO = s.STOCK_ID_PRODUCTO
WHERE s.STOCK_ID_PRODUCTO = 7
```

El resultado de la consulta (Fijense en las existencias) es el siguiente:
[image: Captura del resultado de la consulta de Stock]

El SP no realiza bien los cálculos antes de insertar en la transacción.
La pregunta es ¿Cuál sería la solución a este problema? ¿Cuáles son las alternativas o correcciones que tendría que hacerle al código del SP para que funcione según lo esperado?

Me agradecerían de corazón si me ayudan con este problema. Ah, disculpen si no tengo comentadas las líneas de código, es que suelo comentarlas después de que termino de depurarlo y que todo funcione bien.

Saludos a todos.

Comment: "de alguno de los productos". Qué exactamente significa esto? Si 1 de 10 productos no tiene existencia, de los 10 tendrías que hacer el insert o sólo de ese 1? Es importante diferenciar si el criterio aplica para todos los productos o tienes que hacer un cursor para preguntar por cada producto.

Comment: "y la que me está tirando errores (o mejor dicho, me hace ROLLBACK como consecuencia del error" Cuáles son esos errores?

Comment: @javdromero, te explico. Si me entran en stock una cantidad determinada de 8 productos diferentes, y 5 de ellos ya tenían existencias y los otros 3 no, la idea es que el SP se encargue de realizar los cálculos que mencioné en el post con los 5 productos en existencia, y con los otros 3, al ser la primera vez que reciben entradas de stock, solo se debería insertar las entradas, tanto en las 3 columnas de entradas como en las otras 3 de existencias.

Comment: @javdromero, creo que me equivoqué al explicar la parte del rollback en el post. Ocurre que como el SP falla, y las inserciones están dentro de una transacción, especifiqué que hiciera rollback, por lo tanto esta más que claro que deshace cualquier cambio que se hizo.

Comment: @javdromero Lo que pasa es que como vengo de programar mucho en C# (insertando registros en bases de datos usando bucles), no estoy muy familiarizado con la inserción de múltiples registros desde SQL Server. Por eso tengo esa duda de como hacer ese tipo de inserción.

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que el SP falla por la forma como tienes definido el query SELECT dentro del IF, ya que en la clausula WHERE estas comparando una columna con un resultado obtenido de otro SELECT

Con un INNER JOIN deberia funcionar:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM FICHA_STOCK FS
INNER JOIN @ListaProductos LS ON FS.STOCK_ID_PRODUCTO = LS.DETCOM_ID_PRODUCTO)
```

Comment: Buena idea. No tenía en cuenta usar un INNER JOIN. Lo voy a probar en un rato a ver que pasa después.

Answer (score 0):

Tengo otro problema: Resulta que cuando quiero realizar la orden de compra de 2 o más productos:
[image: Agregando productos desde el programa para realizar la orden de compra]

En la base de datos, cuando ya hay productos ingresados en la Ficha de Stock, estos se insertan multiplicados, y también solo
se insertan aquellos productos estaban previamente en la ficha de stock, y los que todavía no estaban en la ficha de stock en su lugar son reemplazados por los que sí.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y si hago la consulta del detalle de la orden de compra, los productos insertados se muestran correctamente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los ID de producto están bien en el detalle de orden de compra, pero en la ficha de stock se repiten varias veces.

Ahora bien ¿Qué está fallando en el SP?
Reitero que en la ficha de stock se insertan en las 3 columnas de entradas (Vean la descripción de la pregunta) los datos de la orden de compra, y en las existencias, si ya hay productos almacenados en existencia, sumar las cantidades y precios totales y luego dividir ambas para sacar el precio unitario de cada producto. En caso de no haber existencias, que el SP solo inserte las entradas tambien en las existencias.

Esto es muy dificil de resolver.